# MetaMask + Unity iOS build crash on start

Tags: metamask, ios

Unity 2022.2.12 with MetaMask 1.1.1;

Setup:
Bitcode - Disabled; Scriptable backend - IL2CPP; Code Generation - Faster Smaller Builds;

iOS build crashes on startup on the device.

XCode log:

**2023-03-29 14:33:04.245136+0300 TestApp[25201:6314627] Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F3DF865-F418-46B6-841C-936854977AC8/LazySoccer.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework:  dlopen(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F3DF865-F418-46B6-841C-936854977AC8/LazySoccer.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework, 0x0109): Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation10URLRequestV15timeoutIntervalSdvs**

**Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6F3DF865-F418-46B6-841C-936854977AC8/TestApp.app/Frameworks/MetaMask_iOS.framework/MetaMask_iOS**

**Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation**

What's wrong?